# How to watch ts,js,graphql extensions in ts-node-dev?

Tags: node.js, graphql, ts-node, ts-node-dev

I am trying to run the node server by `ts-node-dev` and restart on any any changes in specific files. It is restarting on any changes made to `ts`,`js` files however, it is not restarting on changes to `graphql` files. Any suggestions?

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsnd --transpile-only --rs ./src/microservices/index.ts --watch--extionsions 
 ts,js,graphql"
  }
```

Comment: Hi, i think there's a typo in `--watch--extionsions`. But there's no --watch-extensions flag in ts-node-dev. You can give to the `--watch` flag the path where it needs to look at, i.e. : `...--watch .env, ../common/src, ../gql, .....`

Comment: `ts-node-dev` can have the same flags as `ts-node`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for --watch is different than nodemon and others that allow just a list of extensions.  Here is more regex matching.

I also noticed you do not need to include the standard files it already watches.  Based on the github issue where I found the solution you need to put --watch before the final entry point

In order to watch for .graphql files you need to add

`--watch ./**/*.graphql`

So your example should be:

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsnd --transpile-only --rs --watch ./**/*.graphql ./src/microservices/index.ts"
  }
```